# when Converting my gsp page to pdf i am getting error

Tags: grails

Error stacktrace:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:638)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:709)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:313)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource$XMLResourceBuilder.createXMLResource(XMLResource.java:189)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource.load(XMLResource.java:75)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource$load.call(Unknown Source)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.createDocument(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:55)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.createDocument(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:43)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.createDocument(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:38)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService$createDocument.call(Unknown Source)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:34)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:33)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService$render$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:63)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService$render.call(Unknown Source)
    at RenderingGrailsPlugin$_closure1.doCall(RenderingGrailsPlugin.groovy:48)
    at RenderingGrailsPlugin$_closure1.call(RenderingGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at com.zocampus.ExamScoresController$_closure31.doCall(ExamScoresController.groovy:525)
    at com.zocampus.ExamScoresController$_closure31.doCall(ExamScoresController.groovy)
    at org.grails.jaxrs.web.JaxrsFilter.doFilterInternal(JaxrsFilter.java:46)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Can you show source data? Stacktrace says that you have invalid usage of `&`

Answer (score 2):

**Observation:**

- You are using Grails Rendering Plugin.
- You have an element in the gsp which has a '&' in the text. 
  For example: A label as `<p>S & P 500</p>`

**Solution:**
The string needs to be encoded as HTML. Use `.encodeAsHTML()` in the gsp where you expect '&'.

Sample gsp code:

```
var abc = "S & P 500";
<p>abc.encodeAsHTML()</p>
```