# In Text if "&" word come then it does not allow me to download in grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am using **"Rendering plugin "** for download as **pdf** page...

if in text **"&"** key word comes then it gives me an error.. doesn't allow me to download as pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`encodeAsHTML()` required to avoid the special characters throwing errors. 
Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15999462/2051952).